# How do you add a single element to a CQL set type using the java driver

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to add a single element to a set type using datastax java driver and a bound statement, i.e. (syntax below not tested)

```
CREATE TABLE claims (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  claimed set<text>
);

UPDATE claims SET claimed = claimed + :claimed WHERE id = :id
```

When I run my `BoundStatement`, I receive `Codec not found for requested operation: [set<varchar> <-> java.lang.String]` Do I really have to write a codec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CQL appending (`+`) to a `set` expects a `set`.  Because of this the driver is expecting a `Set<String>` here instead of a `String`.  To fix this, you would nee to wrap your String value in a set, i.e.:

```java
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare("UPDATE claims SET claimed = claimed + :claimed WHERE id = :id");
session.execute(prepared.bind(Collections.singleton("value"), id));
```

Comment: I tried the statement you suggested using `cassandra-driver-core 3.4.0` but I hit this: `Invalid set literal for claimed: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid set literal for claimed: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hrmm, I could have sworn that was supported, what version of C* are you on?

Comment: I stand corrected, it doesn't appear to work, i'll update my answer.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Worked like a charm. Also, if not using a prepared statement (which is not recommended), having the value inline like this worked: `... SET claimed = claimed + {'STRING_VALUE_HERE'}`

Comment: How about if claimed were a user-defined type, registering its codec seem to be tricky. Any example for that?